# h:commandLink not firing the form.submit event

Tags: jsf-2, commandlink

When my page is loaded I execute the following JS script, which I use to display a popup saying (please wait...) when any form is submitted.

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("form").submit(function(){jQuery('#wait-link').trigger('click');return true;});
});
```

This works fine when using **h:commandButton** tag, however when I use the **h:commandLink** tag it doesn't work because the form is submitted by java script (from the file jsf.js in the jar jsf-impl.jar) as shown below

```
mojarra.jsfcljs = function jsfcljs(f, pvp, t) {
  mojarra.apf(f, pvp);
  var ft = f.target;
  if (t) {
    f.target = t;
  }
  f.submit();
  f.target = ft;
  mojarra.dpf(f);
};
```

To solve this problem I copied the **jsf.js** file under **WEB-INF/resources/javax.faces/jsf.js** and modified it to trigger the form submit method using jQuery. This works fine but:

1) I don't like the fact that I am touching the **jsf.js** file since it may change in newer releases of JSF.

2) I don't like the fact that I am using jQuery inside the **jsf.js** file.

Is there a better solution to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bodgan suggested a better solution is to execute the following piece of code when the page is loaded, I don't know what the term is in JS but seems an override for me.

```
jQuery(function(){
  var oldjsfcljs = mojarra.jsfcljs; // save a pointer to the old function

  mojarra.jsfcljs = function jsfcljs(f, pvp, t) {
    jQuery(jq(f.id)).trigger('submit');
    oldjsfcljs.apply(this, arguments);
  };
});

function jq(myid) {
  return '#' + myid.replace(/(:|\.)/g, '\\$1');
}
```

Note: the jq() method is only used to escape the special characters in the form ID.

**update:** the above code seemed to work but if you have parameters in the form it wont so I had to rewrite the mojarra.jsfcljs function as follows:

```
jQuery(function(){
  mojarra.jsfcljs = function jsfcljs(f, pvp, t) {
    mojarra.apf(f, pvp);
    var ft = f.target;
    if (t) {
      f.target = t;
    }

    // trigger the submit event manually.
    jQuery(jq(f.id)).trigger('submit');

    f.submit();
    f.target = ft;
    mojarra.dpf(f);
  };
};
```

Comment: You need a "var" to the oldjsfcljs, otherwise you pollute the global scope.

Comment: Your original code is broken, because you apparently don't know JS. It should be either:


`oldjsfcljs.apply(this, [f, pvp, t]);`

either


`oldjsfcljs.apply(this, arguments);` like in my code. `function.apply()` calls in JS have only 2 parameters: the this object, and a list like object with the arguments.

Comment: You are right about the (arguments) or [f,pvp,t] but this doesn't solve the problem, the problem is that the mojarra.apf(f, pvp) should be called before I trigger the submit event, the apf will add the key/value array pvp as hidden fields in the form and this is what makes it work.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `jsf.ajax.*`, since it is standard as part of the JSF2 spec. In there you have for example `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(callback)` that does what you want.

After you hook in your listener, you can use as much jQuery as you want.

**update:**

If you want to intercept it from your own JS, without touching their stuff you can do:

```
(function() {
    var oldjsfcljs = mojarra.jsfcljs;

    mojarra.jsfcljs = function() { 
        console.log('my stuff before');
        oldjsfcljs.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log('my stuff after');
    }
})();
```

Comment: isn't the jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(callback) used in case of ajax only?

Comment: Yes. Even if for some weird reason you would need it for ANY kind of form, you can still intercept it from JS only, without touching those files:

Comment: Thanks that worked, but I have to mention that the jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(callback) has nothing to do with the problem. I will add the solution below in a separate answer.