# Call bean method before GET request on h:link

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, navigation

I want to invoke method of ViewScoped bean when some h:link is clicked (or opened in new tab or window) before faces servlet begins to handle GET request.

I have a lot of ViewScoped beans for different pages and when I go from one to another I need the first one to put its state into some pocket and the second page to get state from pocket and save it as parent's state.

For h:commandLink there is an action that saves state on click. But h:commandLink cannot be opened in new tab (or can be?). So I want to use h:link in the same way but can't find a place to call method of saving state.

I've tried some manipulations with javascript and creating custom NavigationHandler but they have some drawbacks.

Is there any clear way for doing what I want?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise to see here about opening a new windows with a `<h:commandLink>` : [h:commandLink open in new browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19101713/hcommandlink-open-in-new-browser-window)

This however makes use of third-party libraries, and can be considered as a workaround more than a real solution.

Comment: Thank you! But it's not the option I was looking for. I want to leave the choice of opening (or not opening) a new tab on user side.